# Obtain the slopes of a peak

Tags: matlab, fft, gradient

Let's say I obtained a graph like this from a cross power spectrum:

[image]

where the peak indicates the integer shift of two images.

How can one obtain ***the slope*** of the integer shift from the graph above?

```
I1=imread('someimage1.jpg'); I1=imread('someimage2.jpg'); 

F=(fft2(double(I1)));
G=(fft2(double(I2)));

R=(F.*conj(G))./abs(F.*conj(G)); %cross power spectrum
r=(ifft2(R));
surf(r);
```

Using `regress` would only obtain the slope for the whole dataset, while selecting that specific point of data is not enough to do regress.

```
[m, n]=size(r);
[M,N]=meshgrid(1:m,1:n);
X = [M(:), N(:)];
B=regress(r(:), X);
```

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't know where to begin to find the slope for a peak. :( Some guidance or starting point would definitely helps a lot

Comment: You already have the correct tag: "gradient", so start by using your favourite search engine to look on how to obtain a gradient in MATLAB, which is very easy and looks to be what you want anyway.

Comment: Edited my post.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `regress`, but the logical thing to find a gradient would be either [`diff`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html), or, surprise surprise, [`gradient`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gradient.html). As an aside: using `'EdgeColor','none'` would remove the edges, and thus colour your plot instead of having a big, black mass of edges displayed.

Comment: There's also an image specific gradient: https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imgradient.html you could use to compute a 2D gradient.